# Determine availability zone programmatically from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, availability-zone

Can a running EC2 instance determine what Availability Zone it is running in, without using the AWS API? Perhaps there is a way to have EC2 pass this information in an environment variable or similar?

I'm just hoping to build in a small amount of AZ awareness without adding a dependency on the AWS client library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, using instance [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). For example,

```
az=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
echo ${az}
```

Example output:

```
us-east-1e
```

Depending on your programing language, you can do same. For python, you could use for example `requests` library or native python libraries for calling urls.